# Shopware 6 create product price in custom plugin: product.price vs productPrice

Tags: plugins, shopware6

How do i **create *price* for a product in *custom plugin***?

The database contains a table `product_price` **but** the product has also a attribute `price.*price*`, that confused me.
The default configuration within the *product detail form price card* set only the attribute `product.price`, entity `product_price` keeps empty.

Seems `product.price` to be a simple object, so is it done by following code? I mean, no repository needed?

```
// ../my_price_form.js
...
Component.register('product-pricing-configurator-form', {
    ...
    methods: {
        setPrice() {
            this.product.price["c" + this.currencyId] = {
                net: ...,
                gross: ...,
                linked: true,
                listPrice: null,
                currencyId: this.currencyId
                regulationPrice: null
            }
        }
}
```

Questions:

1. What is the purpose of the entity `product_price`?
2. How do i create the `product.price` attribute?
3. Is there a **documentation available** about create `product.price`?
4. What about the configuration for attribute `product.purchase_price`? Also a simple json object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `product_price` is the table for [advanced pricing](https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-6-en/catalogues/products#advanced-pricing). These prices require a `ruleId` which is the id of a rule build with the [rule builder](https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-6-en/settings/rules). Depending on whether the rule is fulfilled and the priority these prices take precedence over the regular price (`product.price`) or other advanced prices.
2. You pretty much already got it right with the example in your question.
3. See the api reference [here](https://shopware.stoplight.io/docs/admin-api/ZG9jOjEyMzA4NTUy-product-data#currency-price-structure).
4. `purchasePrices` is also an instance of `PriceField` so it's identical in its nature to `price`.